# int org.json.JSONArray.length() on a null object reference

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using volley library to connect to server and I have a Transaction class and a Server class with this codes:

Trans:

```
public class Trans extends Server {
    public Object suggest(Context context) {
        return connect("xxxxxxx", Request.Method.GET);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public Object connect(String url, int method) {
    final Object[] object = {null};
    StringRequest postRequest;
    postRequest = new StringRequest(method, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    object[0] = response;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }
    };
    int socketTimeout = 20000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
    return object[0];
}
```

But when I'm trying to get `JSONArray` with this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ArrayList<Suggests> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) trans.suggest(MainActivity.this);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            Suggests suggests = new Suggests();
            suggests.title = item.getString("title");
            suggests.type = item.getString("type");
            arrayList.add(suggests);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Application force closed and I have this error in `logcat`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc/ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you actually getting a response back from the server? Because your `trans.suggest` function is returning `null`

Comment: yeah I'm sure and i test it with Postman and printed my response in Log everything was fine @ChrisStillwell

Comment: Oh wait, I see the problem... you're returning `object[0]` before your request has time to finish. Instead of returning your object you should make a callback in `onResponse` and pass the value that way.

Comment: oh youre right but how to do that? please post it in an answer so i can accept it @ChrisStillwell

Comment: Volley is **asynchronous**, meaning the `return object[0];` is (most-likely) being executed before `object[0] = response;`

Comment: so how can i return response from server class? @cricket_007

Comment: You don't typically use `return` in a Volley call, you execute it, then perform the action you want from **within** the `onResponse` block

Comment: but I'm working on a project that has many requests with different address of api and parameters to send with post method. so I have to return response and handle them in trans class. there is no way to do this? @cricket_007

Comment: You would need to add an interface parameter for an asynchronous callback to what you currently have or move the Volley method to the `onResume` method.

Comment: how can i add an interface parameter for volley `Stringrequest`? i'm beginner in android programming  @cricket_007

Comment: You actually would add it to the `connect` method, which looks like it would take it from the `suggest` method.

Comment: thanks I think I solved it with your solution @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the suggestions in the comments,

**Step 1** Define an interface that will pass-along the result you want. The `<T>` is a generic type, so you can return whatever data you want. You'll see that in Step 2.

```
public interface AsyncResponse<T> {
    void onResponse(T response);
}
```

**Step 2** Update the Server and Trans classes to take this as a parameter

```
public class Server {

    public void connect(String url, int method, final AsyncResponse<String> asyncResponse) {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (asyncResponse != null) {
                    asyncResponse.onResponse(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VolleyError", error.getMessage());
                Log.e("VolleyError", new String(error.networkResponse.data));
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }
        };

        int socketTimeout = 20000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        request.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

---

Side question: Do you really need the `Context`? It isn't used...

```
public class Trans extends Server {
    public void suggest(Context context, AsyncResponse<String> asyncResponse) {
        connect("xxxxxxxx", Request.Method.GET, asyncResponse);
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Use your method like so to get a result in a callback. This was tested against the url http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, which returns a JSONArray of 10 User objects.

The `ArrayAdapter` was added for a full example since it didn't appear the `ArrayList` in the question was useful for anything.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<User> arrayList;
    private Trans trans;
    private ArrayAdapter<User> adapter;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trans = new Trans();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<User>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        trans.suggest(MainActivity.this, new AsyncResponse<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                arrayList.clear(); // prevent duplicate data

                try {
                    // The URL that was tested returns a JSONArray
                    // Change to JSONObject, if necessary
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        User user = new User();
                        user.username = item.getString("name");
                        user.email = item.getString("email");
                        arrayList.add(user);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Notify since the arrayList has changed the adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man you solved one of the biggest problems i have had. yes i need context because im getting url and port from a config file in assets. but another question: is it possible to sen more than 1 request from different Trans functions to server and get response for each of them?

Comment: You can only accept one response at a time, but yes, you can run many `Trans.suggest` (or whatever you want to call it) methods. Just pass through the async response to volley,  and replace the body of the `onResponse` with whatever you want to do

Comment: no i mean from different functions like Trans.suggest and Trans.login at the same time? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, put a `Trans.login` in the onClick of a button, for example, should work fine. Not quite sure what you're asking

Comment: I'm asking multiple connect() method calling from different functions(for example Trans.suggest and Trans.login) does not make any problem? like wrong data return or 'forceclose'?

Comment: Shouldn't, no. Volley uses the request queue to temporarily hold-off connections until others have finished or the network adapter is busy.

Comment: ok thanks. and btw can you take a look to this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921464/how-to-have-settings-activity-in-a-scrolling-activity